# Are there any benefits using ESAPI's number validations?

Tags: security, bean-validation, owasp, esapi

I have been asked to add some input validation in all of our REST endpoints. We have two custom validation constraints in our system, wrapping around the ESAPI library; one for String, wrapping [#isValidInput](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#isValidInput(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean)) and one for Long, wrapping [#isValidNumber](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#isValidNumber(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20boolean)).

ESAPI's [#isValidNumber](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#isValidNumber(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20boolean)) seems to simply check the number's min and max value (something that I can simply do with JSR-303 [@Min](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.1/api/) / [@Max](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.1/api/)). Are there any added benefits for using the ESAPI library or can I simply remove the custom constraint and add the bean validation annotations?

I do agree that we need the String canonicalization provided by ESAPI, but for the numbers I'm a bit sceptical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any added benefits for using the ESAPI library or can I
>   simply remove the custom constraint and add the bean validation
>   annotations?

In short, yes.  If you notice the last parameter in the call to [#isValidInput](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html#isValidInput(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean)) you linked is whether to turn [canonicalization](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Canonicalization,_locale_and_Unicode) on or off.  If your application turned it off, the only benefit ESAPI will give you is to outsource your validation regex into validation.properties, where if a prod issue arose, you could change the value and restart the server, saving an application build and deployment.  JSR-303 will require a recompile and a deployment.

If however you've left canonicalization on, ESAPI provides one thing that I haven't found in another Java security library to date, which is the ability to detect [mixed encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Mixed_encoding) and [multiple encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding) on a given input string.  From a forensics and incident response perspective, this is ultra-useful as we can tell if our web application is being attacked in real-time, as well as record and audit information about the user performing it.

^^^You seem to know all of this by your last statement.  I haven't seen a web container that didn't pass in `Strings` for numbers.  My guess is that you're pulling it from `request.getParameter("foo");` which means its a string and you still want the defense provided by canonicalize.  Even if it might get caught by a parse exception on the conversion to `Integer` or `Long`, [there's also the risk of overflow or underflow](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/191.html) which could perturb your application in a different way.